# Unique Random Number between 0 and 9

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to generate a unique random number between 0 and 9. The same number cannot be generated twice and the function will be ran 9 time (until all the 9 numbers are used.) Here is the latest way I have been trying to do this:

```
int uniqueRandomInt(int x) {

    std::vector<int> usedRandoms;
    int random = x;

    //Iterate vector
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < usedRandoms.size(); i++) {
        //if passed value is in vector
        if (random = usedRandoms[i]) {
            uniqueRandomInt(random);
        }
        else {
            //If unique rand found put into vector
            usedRandoms.push_back(random);
            return random;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it in another function using:

```
cout << uniqueRandomInt(-1) << endl;
```

Result I am getting is:

```
17801152 (Changes every time the function is called)
```

Am I going about this totally wrong? I did try other ways but with no luck and this is where I'm currently at. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another way to do this is to create a vector with the numbers 0 through 9, randomly shuffle it, and then use the numbers in the vector from front to back.

Comment: *[cough](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) [cough](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)*

Comment: @Greg A vector, or array, not a list.

Comment: See @jaggedSpire 's comment, and also see Fisher-Yates shuffle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I'm using "list" in the more generic sense. However, for sake of pedantry, I'll change it.

Comment: This code is very wrong. You will have a new vector on each recursive iteration and it will be size 0 so your loop wont even be entered anyway. You could make it a static vector, but thats no good as it would hang around for any other calls later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use shuffle.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class T455_t
{
private:
   // data
   std::vector<int> m_iVec ;

public:
   T455_t() {}

   int exec()
      {
         std::vector<int> iVec;

         gen10();

         for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
         {
            int nxtRandom = uniqueRandomInt();
            std::cout << nxtRandom << std::endl;
         }
         return(0);
      }


private: // methods

   void gen10() // fills data attribute with 10 digits
      {
         for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
            m_iVec.push_back(i);

         std::random_device rd;
         std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
         std::shuffle (m_iVec.begin(), m_iVec.end(), gen);
         // m_iVec now contains 10 unique numbers, 
         // range 0..9, in random order
      }

   int uniqueRandomInt()
      {
         assert(m_iVec.size());
         int retVal = m_iVec.back(); // gets last element in vector
         m_iVec.pop_back();          // removes last element
         return(retVal);
      }

}; // class T455_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point  m_start_us =
      std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T455_t   t455;
      retVal = t455.exec();
   }

   std::chrono::microseconds  chrono_duration_us =
      std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::microseconds>
      (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - m_start_us);

   std::cout << "  FINI   " << chrono_duration_us.count() 
             << " us" << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that my compiler did not notice that "iVec" (in the T445_t::exec() method) is not used. clang also did not generate a warning.  Sorry.  I think I might have dropped a compiler option.

Comment: I just noticed the first comment suggested just this technique.  I probably should remove my contribution.  Probably will.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't appear to return a value if `usedRandoms.size()` is zero, which it will be the first time you call the function

```
int uniqueRandomInt(int x) {

    std::vector<int> usedRandoms; // vector.size() = 0
    int random = x;

    // for loop won't be entered
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < usedRandoms.size(); i++)
    {
    }

    // function doesn't return a value
}
```

It's worth noting that it's undefined behaviour to declare a function to return a value, and then not return a value. That's why the *random* values you're getting.

From the C++ standard, 6.6.3 (emphasis mine):

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this **results in undefined behavior in a *value-returning function***.

Comment: And to add to this answer: This mistake of flowing off the end of a function is something the compiler can't always catch. Sure, if there's no `return` statement anywhere in your function then a compiler might warn you about that, but other than that it'd have to be smart enough to be able to decide whether the loop will get entered or not, and that is beyond the capabilities of a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> initVector(){
    vector<int> ret;
    ret.clear();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i){
        ret.push_back(i);
    }

    return ret;

}

int uniqueRendom(){
    static vector<int> randomNumbers = initVector();

    int randomSize = randomNumbers.size() - 1;

    if(randomSize <= 0){
        return -1;
    }

    double randomeNum = (double)rand() / INT_MAX;

    int randomIndex = (int) (randomeNum  * randomSize + 0.5) ;

    int returnValue = randomNumbers[randomIndex];
    randomNumbers.erase(randomNumbers.begin() + randomIndex);

    return returnValue;
}
```

include limits.h for INT_MAX.